# Prime-faces não roda o tema "SAM"

Tags: jsf, primefaces, java-ee, xhtml

Quando executo minha pagina  main.xhtml o tema não é exibido junto a pagina[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue em anexo a arvore do projeto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Arquivo web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>semeru_jsf_maven</display-name> 

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>  
<!-- Duração da sessão -->
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<!-- Configurações do tema do PrimeFaces -->

 <context-param>
<param-name> primefaces.THEME </ param-name>
<valor param> sam </ param-value>
</ context-param>

<!-- Configurações do PrimeFaces --> 
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.resource.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/primefaces_resource/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Arquivo faces-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
          version="2.0">

<lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>br.com.semeru.util.PhaseListenerSemeru</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>
```

**Arquivo main.xhtml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

```
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="./css/default.css"/>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="./css/cssLayout.css"/>
    <title>Facelets Template</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>

    <div id="top">
        <ui:insert name="top">Top</ui:insert>
    </div>

    <div id="content" class="center_content">
        <ui:insert name="content">Content</ui:insert>
    </div>

    <div id="bottom">
        <ui:insert name="bottom">Bottom</ui:insert>
    </div>

</h:body>
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar com este projeto, sou leigo ao usar o Primefaces.

Comment: Você incluiu em seu projeto a lib do tema? http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/themes/sam/1.0.10/

Comment: Rodrigo eu inclui o tema "SAM" em uma biblioteca e adicionei ao projeto, coloquei um anexo da minha arvore do projeto, sou novo com o primefaces, então fico um pouco perdido!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro está no seu Web.xml. Nesta parte:

```
<!-- Configurações do tema do PrimeFaces -->
<context-param>  
  <param-name>META-INF.maven.org.primefaces.themes.sam</param-name>  
  <param-value>sam</param-value>  
</context-param>
```

O correto para se utilizar um tema no Primefaces é desta forma:

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>nomeDoSeuTema</param-value>
 </context-param>
```

Fonte: http://www.primefaces.org/themes

Comment: adelmo00 eu coloquei o código informado por vc, para utilização do primefaces, e msm assim ele ainda me exibe a mesma pagina.

Comment: @MichellXexeu vi que o nome do seu tema é sam. Esse tema está no diretório correto ou o .jar está mapeado no pom.xml?

Comment: Adelmo00 inclui a arvore do projeto acima, adicionei o tema sam em uma lib.